# How to create dynamic select field with blank option and unfiltered state

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I need to create a dynamic select field in Rails 3.2, where the options available in the second fields (states) depends on the value of the first (country). I've referred to the revised version of this Railscast, and am using the following code:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#person_state_id').parent().hide()
  states = $('#person_state_id').html()
  $('#person_country_id').change ->
    country = $('#person_country_id :selected').text()
    escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(states).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_country}']").html()
    if options
      $('#person_state_id').html(options)
      $('#person_state_id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#person_state_id').empty()
      $('#person_state_id').parent().hide()
```

I need to make two changes to this code, which I think should be pretty straightforward for someone with stronger javascript skills than I have.

1. In the filtered list, I need to include a blank option. Currently selecting a country results in the first state state in the filetred list being selected. I need to leave the prompt "please select". How can I do this?

**EDIT**

SMathew's suggestions helped here. I'm using `$('#person_state_id').html(options).prepend('<option></option>')` which, together with a prompt attribute on the html tag, acheives the required result.

1. If no country is selected (ie the `else` statement) `person_state_id` should contain a complete, unfiltered list of all states. I've tried:

   `else
     $('#person_state_id').html(states)`

But this is not behaving as expected. I'm having these issues.

1. If I select a country that has associated state records, #person_state_id options are correctly filtered (and with smathews suggestion, a prompt is included).
2. If I select a country with no associated state records, #person_state_id contains all states, a blank option in the markup, but the first state option is selected by default. (It should be empty, with a blank option selected by default and a prompt displayed).
3. If I clear the selection in #person_country_id, #person_state_id contains an unfiltered list of all states (correct), and an empty option in the markup (correct) but the first state record is selected by default (should be a prompt).

How can I resolve these issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
...

if (options) {
  $('#person_state_id').html(options).prepend('<option>Please select</option>').parent().show()
} else {
   $('#person_state_id').html(states).prepend('<option>Please select a state</option>').parent().show()
}
```

Comment: thanks @smathew. the `prepend` action works perfectly. Do you think `..else { $('#person_state_id').html(states)...` is correct? It's the approach I've tried, but is not behaving as expected. I'll update my question with more details. Appreciate any ideas you may have.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Actually I'm not using the hide/show part anyway. I've added some more detail to my question, and welcome any suggestions you may have

Answer (score 0):

To deal with my second problem, I added the following coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
  resetCountry = ->
    $('#person_state_id').select2 "val", "0" 
  $('#person_country_id').bind("change", resetCountry);
```

This, coupled with smathew's answer, seems to be working

(I'm using select2 to format my select fields. You'll need a different approach to set the value if not using select2)